Is there a single keyboard shortcut for going to the end of the above line?
I want to go to the end of the above line. I can do this with two keyboard shortcuts, namely <up> followed by C-e. Can it be done in one in an out-of-the-box copy of Emacs? I could surely write the code myself, but does such a binding already exist by default?

I don't think there's a key for that by default but you could certainly define a command that does it and bind that command, e.g., by combining the commands for <up> and C-e, or by just having the command invoke move-end-of-line with an argument of 0:
(defun my-move-end-of-previous-line ()
  (interactive)
  (move-end-of-line 0))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-e") #'my-move-end-of-previous-line)

